# Play/Pause with the same button

Tags: ios, objective-c, audio, playback, resume

How to make a `play/Pause` button with the same piece of code.

```
- (IBAction)min:(id)sender 
{
  NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"1min" ofType:@"mp3"];
  AVAudioPlayer *theAudio = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path] error:NULL];
                  theAudio.delegate = self;
                  theAudio.numberOfLoops = -1;
                  [theAudio play];
                  [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:@"-" forKey:@"music"]; 
}
```

How can I resume by the same button?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use this to identify button state:

In .h file make `theAudio` declaration :

```
AVAudioPlayer *theAudio;
```

In your method :

```
UIButton *button = (UIButton *)sender;

button.selected = !button.selected;

if(button.selected)
{
   // Play
   NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"1min" ofType:@"mp3"];
   theAudio = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path] error:NULL];
   theAudio.delegate = self;
   theAudio.numberOfLoops = -1;
   [theAudio play];
   [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:@"-" forKey:@"music"];
}
else
{
  // Pause
  [theAudio pause];
}
```

Comment: could please write more detail on // Play and  // Pause part?

Comment: @Anusha what does this step imply "button.selected = !button.selected;"?

Answer (score 0):

Create a boolean, such as `buttonIsPlayButton`. Set it to true at the start if the button is a play button. Then when the button is pressed, set it to false. You should have the image change each time the button is pressed based on the value of the boolean.